# Syntax highlighting for JavaScript block in WebStorm editor

Tags: javascript, webstorm

When the mouse pointer is inside a code block, syntax highlighting occurs only within that block, and the rest of the code outside the block remains unhighlighted. How can I make the code highlight throughout the entire file regardless of the mouse cursor position?

[image]

I reached out to the GPT chat, tried googling the question, but still couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I need an image to demonstrate the syntax highlighting specifically in the WebStorm IDE. The code itself doesn't carry any meaningful content.

Comment: What **custom plugins** do you have installed. List them all here. Sounds like one of them to me... P.S. AFAIK the IDE core has such or similar feature, but it's not in the Settings/Preferences screen (means: you cannot enable it easily). So most likely it's a custom plugin (own functionality or by enabling such a option internally). Anyway: [IDEA-291083](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291083)